# Website makes IE8 crash

Tags: internet-explorer-8, crash

I'm having a simple but still very annoying issue and i have no idea where to start looking. Its a website i've been taking over and it crashes hard right away when opening in IE8 version 8.0.6001.18702.

The site is http://www.dhf.dk/DHF.aspx and i have to suspect some invalid manipulation of DOM but i like i said i have no idea where to start looking.

Error message is

```
AppName: iexplore.exe    AppVer: 8.0.6001.18702  ModName: mshtml.dll
ModVer:  8.0.6001.18975  Offset: 00067838
```

I suspect the object-embed code to be faulty but im not hardcore enough in html to be sure if its the case

```
<object id="DhfSlideshow" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="610px" height="417px" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
    <param name="movie" value="/Frontend/Flash/slideshow.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="dataUrl=/Frontend/DHF/DHF.Widget.Slideshows.Album/Server/DHF.Widget.Slideshows.Album.ashx?albumId=a68eae5f-955b-4ba0-aa11-6e4d68ead5df&amp;color_scheme=/red/flash/&amp;overviewUrl=s" />
    <embed align="middle" wmode="transparent" width="610px" quality="high" height="417px" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" loop="false" name="DhfSlideshow" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars="dataUrl=/Frontend/DHF/DHF.Widget.Slideshows.Album/Server/DHF.Widget.Slideshows.Album.ashx?albumId=a68eae5f-955b-4ba0-aa11-6e4d68ead5df&amp;color_scheme=/red/flash/&amp;overviewUrl=s" play="true" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" src="/Frontend/Flash/slideshow.swf"></embed>

</object>
```

Comment: Does it throw any javascript errors, etc in other browsers? Have you tried it in IE7 and/or IE9? Have you got IE8 patched up to the latest version? (it may be a security flaw, in which case there may be a patch for it)

Comment: No javascript errors... the page doesn't even render, IE just throws the error-popup box. I've narrowed it down to only happening on the frontpage, and what is unique about it looks to be flash. It doesn't help so much to disable the flash-plugin though, so maybe some params in the html that is illegal?

Comment: What kind of HTML do you have on your page(Cannot access the link from here:( )? Do you have a drop down box/multiselect box? I have faced a similar issue in the past.

Comment: @apache i suspect the flash-embed code to be the sinner... i've updated my question with source of the embed

Comment: So your page works if you remove the embed code?

Comment: i don't have access to edit the html - yet :P i was just asked to identify the problem :/

Comment: @Pauli - yeah, you can edit it. Use Wget or similar to download the page to disk (without going via a browser). Then you should be able to play with it on your local machine as much as you like.

Comment: @spudley i keep getting this info-bar in IE about loading activeX content, which i don't get when its running from the internet. When i choose "Allowed blocked content" the page renderers correctly, except for the flash elements of course, which i suppose is because of cross-site loading restrictions of flash.

Comment: @Pauli - well, if nothing else, it sounds like that's helped to narrow down the problem. have you tried disabling Flash in the browser before visiting the URL?

Comment: @Spudley Yes, i've disabled all the add-ons but the page still makes IE8 crash.

Comment: @Pauli - wow. that's pretty hairy. I assume you've confirmed it really is disabled (ie visit a site like youtube and check that nothing plays)?

Comment: Meh... i inserted a <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" /> on the page and now it works... next question i guess is what i need to do to make it ie8 compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that *all* the other templates for the website had a `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />` tag on them, and correctly... after inserting on the frontpage as well the page rendered in IE without crashing.

I can't even begin to imagine where to look, so i'll guess that has to wait until a makeover at some point.